Determine if a managed object is disposed
I am troubleshooting a large code base and one of the recurring problems I identified was the following:
An instance of the Bitmap object is assigned to a PictureBox. When the image needs to be replaced, the code disposes the object and replaces it with a newly created object (in that order). The solution, of course, is to disassociate the bitmap from the control before disposing it.
Please note that this is a specific example, but this could apply to any situation. Catching the ObjectDisposed exception is not enough (there isn't one). In the example above, the containing control throws its own GDI-based exception: Parameter is not valid.
I am not suggesting this as an approach. I simply want to know if it is possible to detect if an arbitrary managed object is disposed (as long as we have a reference to it of course).

You could wrap the resource in another IDisposable and track when .Dispose() is called.

@DanielA.White, thanks. I have already done that. The question, however, is more general since I was thinking about writing code to make troubleshooting easier. Troubleshooting 1M LOC is tough man! :)

I think it's not possible, as Dispose can be implemented in arbitrary way by a developer. Thus, you do not have any guarantee that what worked for one object, will work for the other. For situation at hand, you can inspect source code for Bitmap class and its base Image class to see if you can investigate Dispose method and look for indicators within the class (maybe inspect public members that get affected by disposal).

The short answer is no.
The IDispoable interface does not provide any means of telling user code that an instance implementing it actually disposed, and it's up to the developers writing the user code to write it in such a way that an instance would be disposed when it's no longer needed.
You can, of course, create your own interface inherited from IDisposable that will add an IsDisposed property and wrap your IDisposable classes with a class implementing this interface but that would still require the user code to use that property to benefit from that. A better way to handle it would be to fix the code that's using the IDisposable instances.

.NET object disposing feature doesn't relate to any memory management activity and thus it's not inherent for any type automatically.
Since automatic memory management was implemented, object destructors aren't called deterministically any more. The programmer should care itself to release unmanaged resource. The standard way proposed in .NET is IDisposable (supported by c# compiler with the using statement) but it can be any up to the programmer and it should be explicitly implemented.
You can determine if a managed object is disposed only if the object provides such functionality (e. g. implements IDisposable and provides additional property like IsDisposed).
You need to embed this function into every type you need to monitor.
PictureBox implements the Disposed event which you need to handle. Unfortunately, it's not a part of IDisposable and we should not expect this event anywhere, moreover other .NET types like Stream for example don't implement it.
Calling the Dispose method, you don't kill the object. You can "dispose" the object in such way as much as you need:
public class MyResource: IDisposable
{
    // Pointer to an external unmanaged resource.
    private IntPtr handle;

    // Other managed resource this class uses.
    private Component component = new Component();

    // Track whether Dispose has been called.
    private bool disposed = false;

    // To determine outside is object disposed or not
    public bool IsDisposed => disposed; 

    public MyResource(IntPtr handle) { this.handle = handle; }

    public NewHandle(IntPtr handle) {
        // Do not care about managed resources in demo
        this.handle = handle; disposed = false;
    }

    public void Dispose() => Dispose(disposing: true);

    // Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
    // If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly
    // or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
    // can be disposed.
    // If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the
    // runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference
    // other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed
            // and unmanaged resources.
            if(disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources.
                component.Dispose();
            }
            // Call the appropriate methods to clean up
            // unmanaged resources here.
            // If disposing is false,
            // only the following code is executed.
            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            // Note disposing has been done.
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // Use interop to call the method necessary
    // to clean up the unmanaged resource.
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    // Use C# finalizer syntax for finalization code.
    // This finalizer will run only if the Dispose method
    // does not get called.
    // It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize.
    // Do not provide finalizer in types derived from this class.
    ~MyResource()
    {
        // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here.
        // Calling Dispose(disposing: false) is optimal in terms of
        // readability and maintainability.
        Dispose(disposing: false);
    }
}

...

using (var myres = new MyResource())
{
    myres.Dispose();
    // we can still use myres
    myres.NewHandle(new Handle());
}
// Disposed in the second time by leaving the using block.
// Since myres is the local variable in the block above
// the referenced object is released now and available for garbage collection
// but it's not related to object's disposing cycle.

// Alternatively:
var myres = new MyResource())
myres.Dispose();
myres.NewHandle(new Handle());
myres.Dispose();
myres = null;
// No way to interact with myres any more.
// The referenced object is released now and available for garbage collection.

If application doesn't reach a memory limit, destructors are called when application exits.

Since we have a reference to the object, is there no way to query the garbage collector to find out if it has processed it?

To be precise, disposing and garbage collector processing do not relate each other. Disposing is the interface intentionally and explicitly implemented by some types only. From other side, GC recovers object's memory when no variables reference it. While we have a variable to interact with the object, it's not "touched" by GS. The ways to track objects is dependency injection, fabricating etc.

Automatic Memory Management explains memory management in .NET

Since automatic memory management was implemented, object destructors aren't called deterministically any more. The programmer should care itself to release unmanaged resource. The standard way proposed in .NET is IDisposable but it can be any up to the programmer and it should be explicitly implemented.

Consider that the IDisposable interface has c# compiler support with the using statement.

@GSerg What does Stream do? I wrote "the Disposed event ... types like Stream for example don't implement it". Did I miss the Disposed event in the Stream class?

@GSerg "No you cannot"? If the class allows you to determine if the object is disposed why you can not to do it? Sure, if a class implements IDisposable only, you cannot. But required functionality can be added.

How do you suppose to add the required functionality to all built-in classes of .NET, such as Bitmap? Did I miss the Disposed event in the Stream class- no, I misread this part of your answer, so I have deleted my comment.
